# vNext : Exception on running a console app 'Could not load type 'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions, from assembly mscordlib

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have created a simple console application with vNext and deployed into a environment **which has not installed .Net.**

I am getting this exception when I run the application

> Exception on running a console app 'Could not load type
>   'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions, from assembly mscordlib

Could I make it work without having to install .Net?

Thanks for your time.

Just in case here is my project.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231"
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22231"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to run `kpm restore` in your project folder

Comment: Hi @Mike I get the same error as before by running "kpm restore"

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same exception trying to run the selfhosted vNext "StarterWeb" application. The box is a Windows 2008 with no Framework 4.5 installed. Is this connected to the still-beta state of vNext?